# Using setConnection on Laravel 4 Models

Tags: php, mysql, model, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to set the connection in use by a model in Laravel 4 before getting instances of the model from a secondary database. I have correctly filled in the information for the secondary connection in `Config/database.php`, but for some reason Laravel is reverting back to the default connection when I make the call to `$userModel->all()`

```
$userModel = new User;
$userModel->setConnection('secondary_connection');
$users = $userModel->all();
```

Which gives the error

``` SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'boradmin_master.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from ``users``) (Bindings: array ( )) ```

Which I have traced back to possibly happening due to some code in the `Model::all()` function:

```
* @param  array  $columns
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
*/
public static function all($columns = array('*'))
{
    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->get($columns);
}
```

So my question is, how do I get Laravel to respect my desire to use the connection name I gave in `$userModel->setConnection('secondary_connection')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent's `all()` will create a new model before executing the method all(), so you need to tell it to select a connection statically, but you were trying to do it dinamically, by instantiating your model before calling `all()`.

Have you tried this?:

```
User::on('secondary_connection')->get();
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. You have to use `User::on('secondary_connection')->get();`, since Query/Builder doesn't have an "all" method.